# box2d and Starling - Bodies not colliding correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, starling-framework

Testing out my flash based iOS billiard game:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hinx2j67xzq3ovs/poolX.jpg

I discovered that the white ball sometimes simply goes through the other balls,
while it collides with the other.

Is there a setting I miss?

I set the white ball body to awake before applying SetLinearVelocity().

Do other bodies need to be set awake or what?

Mirza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `isBullet=true` property on your ball body. ([not proper collision in box2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16458178/not-proper-collision-in-box2d/16458452#16458452))

Comment: only on white ball or on all?

Comment: @mirzahat try only on a white, because afaik it can affect the performance

Comment: ok, thx, any links where I can find tips on box2d + starling performance for mobile?

Comment: @mirzahat their performances goes separately, because one works on CPU and the second on GPU. i know that this is a great book: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024217.do

Comment: @Cherniv Indeed that's a really good book from Thibault Imbert and it's FREE :) on the android books market.